What is the Android Studio Unknown Device and how can I get rid of it?
It's been a while since my Android Studio strangely "created" this unknown device like in the screenshot below:

This device start booting as soon as I open the Android Studio, I can't remove it since it says it is a physical device, the device explorer shows no information, just a single empty folder. And the device never completes the boot sequence.
Any ideas on what it can be or how to remove it completely?
I'm on a windows machine btw if that's relevant and working on a Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2 Beta 2

Do you see any adb devices in Windows device manager? What is the output of adb devices? Have you recently used adb WiFi pairing or adb connect?

No adb devices on Windows device manager, I was suspecting HyperV but dont know. Also when I use adb devices it shows 1 emulator (correct) 1 physical (corret) and this one with id: FW914-HM-408-G8-50-23112015-SPD???. Pretty weird
